# CRM 2013/2015 Navigation breadcrumbs issue with custom html page

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have a sitemap link that opens a custom html page (web resource). 
The page looks like the settings > administration page and has links to other entity grids (homepages).
These entity grids are only available through this custom page and are not part of the CRM sitemap.

i.e. Settings > Extensions > Backoffice (my custom page) > Custom new_testentity Grid > new new_testentity form

My issue is that the new_testentity form shows the Backoffice custom page in the navbar and not the new_testentity Grid. 
This means that when the user wants to navigate back to the grid he need to take the long way around i.e. form > Backoffice (link to grid) > Grid

Has anyone encountered this issue? 
Is there any way to include the grid in the breadcrumb?

**Update:** I noticed that built-in CRM pages produce the same behavior. 
When you navigate to Settings > System (area) > Administration > Users (Grid) > User Form the navigational breadcrumb on the User's form shows the Administration (back) link and doesn't allow direct navigation to the Users Grid.